# how to filter firebase object using field inside list

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am an android developer, but this is not really important. I accept solution also in other programming language.

I have a collection of "answers" under /root/answers. Here the data is stored using push method, so each child has a unique id. Each child has a field called "user_ref" which is a simple string. I need to populate my list with all answers where a given string match with "user_ref". 
So I built my DatabaseReference with:

```
DatabaseReference r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ANSWERS_REF)
            .startAt("id_123")
            .endAt("id_123")
            .getRef();
```

It works but every time this Database references return all answers and not only selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by calling `getRef()` at the end of your statement. That returns the `DatabaseReference` of the location that you query, so that is all answers.

```
DatabaseReference allAnswers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ANSWERS_REF);
Query r = allAnswers.startAt("id_123")
                    .endAt("id_123");
```

Since `Query` is the base class of `DatabaseReference`, you can also attach listeners to the `Query`.

```
r.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { ...
```

Comment: I mark this anwer as solution because you have reason, even if my error was to user reference intead of Query object for FirebaseAdapter

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `equalTo("id_123")` instead of `startAt()` and `endAt()` (I am assuming that id_123 is a value for user_ref). Namely as follows,

```
DatabaseReference r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ANSWERS_REF)
            .orderByChild("user_ref")
            .equalTo("id_123")
            .getRef();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried also this solution, but the result is the same. I apply this ref to FirebaseUI adapter